# Back button Navigation in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android to development. I have a problem while I press back button.

If I use the finish that particular view gets destroyed. Next time I press back button, the app ends.
I need controlled navigation with back button

for example these are my activities A,B,C,D

my flow should be

from activity A to B to C to D to A

and user can navigate in between D to A

but when the user Navigates from D to A

again if he presses the back button

it should not navigate to any other activity

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You want to navigate to Activity A from D. So, you can call Activity A from D as below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //clears B and C from stack.
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want an activity to retain its state on back press just don't call the finish() method before starting other activity on top of it. Android will take care of taking to the previous activity when you will press back button, given that there is no entry `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Just override the

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();//comment this if you want to implement your own logic
        //Do whatever you like
    }
```

on your A activity and start the D activity.

Answer (score 0):

In D override onBackPress

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Just type this in Activity A same as it is,Nothing to change

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the activity is called from another activity, calling activity goes into stack according to activity life cycle. When you move from A to B, A is stored into stack and B is opened. You want to go (A to B to C to D to A), (D to A or vice verse) but not from B to A or C to B or D to C or A to D when you press button.

When you are calling activity C from B also call finish() to destroy B and similarly when you are calling D from C to destroy C so that you cannot go backward. This will restrict your flow.

class A extends Activity{

//Button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

}

class B extends Activity{

//Button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(B.this,C.class);
startactivity(intent);
finish();
```

}

class C extends Activity{

//Button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(C.this,D.class);
startactivity(intent);
finish();
```

}

class D extends Activity{

//Button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(D.this,A.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

}

In this way when you go from A to B -> A is stored in the stack, B to C -> B is destroyed (using finish), C to D -> C is destroyed, and You can go directly from D to A using back button. If you press again back button after going from D to A, it will come to D, and again press back it will come to A (first activity launched.) and then after pressing back again App will end.